# Ubuntu18.04 - Anaconda navigator update issue

Tags: ubuntu, anaconda

every time i open anaconda navigator 1.9.2 it asks me to update to 1.9.4 as it is available. However, when i try to update through the GUI I get "conda multierror" as shown in this screenshot [Anaconda-navigaor update error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV2hs.png).

I have also tried to run the update through the terminal but i receive several errors like this

```
"CondaVerificationError: The package for anaconda-navigator located at /home/vr/anaconda3/pkgs/anaconda-navigator-1.9.4-py37_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/tests/__pycache__/test_endpoint_content.cpython-37.pyc'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found."
```

The only thing I can do is downgrading to 1.8.7 and re-upgrading to 1.9.2.
Can anyone help with that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved by uninstalling Anaconda 5.3.0 and installing 5.3.1.